# Normalize data model in RxJava without for loops and temporary arrays

Tags: functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable

Given the following response from a api request I would like to normalize the datamodel into a simpler one using rxjava without using any loops or temporary arrays to store information.

```html
Given: List<MyItem> 
===================

MyItem
String category_name
List<Switch> switches;

Switch
String id
boolean active

Response:
[{
 "category_name": "Sport",
 "switches": [{
  "id": "sport_01",
  "active": true
 }, {
  "id": "sport_02",
  "active": false
 }, {
  "id": "sport_03",
  "active": true
 }]
}, {
    "category_name": "Economy",
 "switches": [{
  "id": "economy_01",
  "active": true
 }, {
  "id": "economy_02",
  "active": true
 }] 
}]

Expected Normalised: List<MyViewModel>
===========================
MyViewModel
String categoryName
String switchId
boolean switchActiveState

Example 
[{
 "category_name": "Sport",
 "id": "sport_01",
 "active": true
}, {
 "category_name": "Sport",
 "id": "sport_02",
 "active": false
}, ...
]
```

My first approach was the following

```html
Observable<MyItem> mMyItemObservable = mApi.getReponse()
                .map(mToMyItemList)
                .flatMapIterable(mToMyItem)
                .share();

Observable<Switch> switchObservable = mMyItemObservable.flatMap(new Func1<MyItem, Observable<List<Switch>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<Switch>> call(final MyItem item) {
                return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<List<Switch>>>() {
                    @Override public Observable<List<Switch>> call() {
                        return Observable.just(item.switches);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Switch>, Iterable<Switch>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Switch> call(List<Switch> switches) {
                return switches;
            }
        });
```

I have tried to use the following

```
Observale.zip(mMyItemObservable, switchObservable, Func...)
Observale.combineLatest(mMyItemObservable, switchObservable, Func...)
```

in order to produce the endResult List but with no success because most probably the length of the 2 observables were different.
ie. mMyItemObservable with length 2 (items) and the switchObservable with length 5 items.

Any ideas of alternative ways to group these 2 observables together to achieve the end result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the 2-element version of `flatMap`:

```
mMyItemObservable = 
   mApi.getReponse()
       .map(mToMyItemList)
       .flatMapIterable(mToMyItem)
       .flatMap(item -> Observable.from(item.switches),
          (item, switch) -> new MyViewModel(item, switch)
       );
```

Also please tell whoever gave you this homework to a) get into the 21st century and drop all the m- prefixes b) start using Java 8 features on Android (makes life with RxJava much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It looks like is an ideal solution. I wasn't aware about the existence of the 2-func element flatmap.